# What is the syntax in this typedef statement doing?

Tags: c++

I ran across a line of code that looks like the following:

`typedef Foo* (*CREATE_BAR)(uint32_t);`

How exactly does this work? What is happening in this code?

Comment: It's at times like these when http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/ is helpful... Of course you'd have to already know that `Foo` was a type and swap it for a primitive type, like: [`int* (*CREATE_BAR)(uint32_t)`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int*+%28*CREATE_BAR%29%28uint32_t%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a function pointer type named `CREATE_BAR` which accepts a `uint32_t` argument and returns a `Foo*`. It could hold a pointer to any such function.

Answer (score 2):

It is a type for a pointer on function returning `Foo*`, and taking `uint32_t`

In c++11, it would be

```
using CREATE_BAR = Foo* (*)(uint32_t);
```